# No group of order 10000 is simple

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, sylow-theory, simple-groups

A proof of this fact was already given here: [No group of order 10,000 is simple](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188162/no-group-of-order-10-000-is-simple)

However, I am wondering whether or not the following proof works as well:

By way of contradiction, suppose $G$ is simple and $|G| = 10000 = 5^42^4$. Sylow theory gives $|\operatorname{Syl}_5(G)| = 1$ or $16$. If $|\operatorname{Syl}_5(G)| = 1$, then there is a Sylow 5-subgroup that is normal, and so we would have a contradiction. So suppose that $|\operatorname{Syl}_5(G)| = 16$. Consider the action of $G$ on $\operatorname{Syl}_5(G)$ by conjugation and let $$\phi : G \to S_{16}$$ be the associated permutation representation. The map $\phi$ is nontrivial since the action is transitive by the second part of Sylow theory, which says that all Sylow p-subgroups are conjugate of each other. This show that the kernel of $\phi$ is not all of $G$. Also, note that $10^4 = 5^4\times 2^4$ does not divide $16!$, since $16! = 2^{15} \times 3^6\times 5^3\times 7^2\times 11\times 13$, and this prime factorization does not contain $5^4$. Hence $\phi$ is not injective, and so the kernel is not trivial. Hence $\ker(\phi)$ is a proper nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$, which contradicts out assumption that $G$ is simple.

Comment: I might be missing something, but this is the argument given in brief by the accepted solution to the linked problem. e: Here the action on left cosets of the normalizer of a given sylow 2-subgroup is quite similar to the conjugation action on the set of sylow 2-subgroups

Comment: This is *not* a proof by contradiction: you have two possible cases, for which you find a non-trivial normal subgroup, hence in each case $G$ is not simple.

Comment: @RolfHoyer So this a valid and complete proof, even though I am using a different action than the other proof?