# Simple group of order 10000

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, simple-groups

> Prove that no group of order 10,000 is simple.

Here is my attempt.

> For contradiction, suppose $G$ of order $10000$ is simple. Notice that
> $$10,000 = 5^4 \cdot 16.$$
> By the Sylow theorems, $n_5 = 1 + 5k$ for $k \geq 0$ and $n_5 \mid 16$. Going through the cases:
> \begin{align*}
> k = 0 \implies n_5 = 1 & & \text{divides $16$} \\
> k = 1 \implies n_5 = 6 & & \text{doesn't divide $16$} \\
> k = 2 \implies n_5 = 11 & & \text{doesn't divide $16$} \\
> k = 3 \implies n_5 = 16 & & \text{divides $16$} \\
> k = 4 \implies n_5 = 20 & & \text{doesn't divide $16$}
> \end{align*}
> So $n_5 = 1$ or $n_5 = 16$, but since we're taking $G$ to be simple, we have $n_5 \neq 1$, so $n_5 = 16$.

At this point I know that I need to construct an isomorphism between $G$ and some subgroup of $S_{16}$, using conjugation, and then use Lagrange's theorem. but I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188162/no-group-of-order-10-000-is-simple?rq=1

Comment: Though that link helps, I can't fully understand it. In particular, I don't understand the introduction of the normalizer or the construction of the homomorphism.

Comment: Okay. So the key is that $G$ acts on the set of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ by conjugation.

Sylow's theorem tells us this action is transitive (i.e., that all the Sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugates of one another). As with all group actions, we get a homomorphism from $G$ to the group of permutations of $\mathrm{Syl}_p(G)$. If $G$ is simple then this homomorphism must have trivial kernel, and therefore $G$ is isomorphic to its image in $\mathrm{Syl}_p(G)$. But that implies the order of $G$ divides the order of $\mathrm{Syl}_p(G)$ (Lagrange's theorem). This is impossible.

Comment: The homomorphism is called the permutation representation. The normalizer $\mathrm{N}_G(P)$ is the stabilizer of $P$ under the action of $G$ by conjugation on $\mathrm{Syl}_p(G)$. Equivalently, it's the kernel of the permutation representation of the action.

It's a consequence of Sylow's theorems that $\mathrm{Syl}_p(G)$ is the index of the $\mathrm{N}_G(P)$. You can prove this using the orbit-stabilizer theorem. I recommend reviewing group actions if you have time.

Answer (score 2):

If using the action on $G$ by conjugation is slightly difficult for you to grasp, here might be another lengthier method to go about solving this question. (I hope its right)!

Let $n_5=16$. Let $P$ and $Q$ be two sylow-5 subgroups of order $625$ each. Now we know
$$|P \cap Q|=\frac{|P|.|Q|}{|PQ|} \geq \frac{|P|.|Q|}{|G|} \sim 39.06$$
But we know that $|P \cap Q|$ divides 625 as $P \cap Q \subset P$ and so $|P \cap Q|=125$.
This implies $|PQ|=3125$

Now as $[P:P \cap Q]=[Q: P \cap Q]=5$, which is the smallest prime divisor of 625, $P \cap Q \triangleleft P$ and $P \cap Q \triangleleft Q$.

Let $N=N_G(P \cap Q)$. Then, as $P \cap Q$ is normal in both P and Q, we have $P \subset N$ and $Q \subset N$. Now,

$p(P \cap Q)p^{-1}=P \cap Q \ \ \ \forall p \in P$ (as $P \cap Q \triangleleft P$)

and

$q(P \cap Q)q^{-1}=P \cap Q \ \ \ \forall q \in Q$ (as $P \cap Q \triangleleft Q$).

Therefore, for any $pq \in PQ$, we have
$$pq(P \cap Q)(pq)^{-1}=pq(P \cap Q)q^{-1}p^{-1}=p(P \cap Q)p^{-1}=P \cap Q$$
and so we have $PQ \subset N$ and $|PQ| \leq |N|$.

So $|N| \geq 3125$, and it must also be a divisor of $10,000$ and divisible by $625$ (as $P \subset N$ and $Q \subset N$). The only possibilities then are $5000$ and $10000$.

If $|N|=5000$, then its index in $G$ must be 2 and hence it is normal. If $|N|=10000$, then $P \cap Q$ is normal in $G$. Therefore $G$ cannot be simple.

Comment: It's slightly quicker to use Sylow's theorem on $N$. Since $|{\rm Syl}_5(N)| > 1$ and it divides the order of $|N|$ and hence of $|G|$, we must have $|{\rm Syl}_5(N)|  = 16$, but then $16$ divides $|N|$, so $N=G$. But, for this particular example, the fact that $5^4$ does not divide $16!$ is an easier argument.

Comment: Oh right, that didn't strike me! Thank you so much!